# How do I display a popover next to a jquery's autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have a page with an input field that has a jquery autocomplete dropdown. Currently, when one of the autocomplete options is hovered over, a div is displayed elsewhere on the page.

```
$("#MyInputField").autocomplete({
  focus: function (e, ui) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET"
    url: "/Json/GetMoreAutoCompleteDetails" + ui.item.id,
    success: function (result){
      $('#SomeDiv').show();
      },
    }
  }
});
```

I'm trying to replace 'SomeDiv' with a popover window. I've modified the above code like so:

```
$("#MyInputField").autocomplete({
  focus: function (e, ui) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET"
    url: "/Json/GetMoreAutoCompleteDetails" + ui.item.id,
    success: function (result){
      $(ui.item).popover({
        'content': function(){
          return $('#SomeDiv');
          },
          'html': true,
          'trigger': 'hover'
          }
        });
      },
    }
  }
});
```

The HTML for the popover contents is:

```
<div id="SomeDiv" class="hide">
  <div id="somePopoverField"></div>
</div>
```

This is intended to display a popover next to the autocomplete menu item that's currently being hovered over. However, I know that "ui.item" is incorrect, because it doesn't work. What do I need to target in order to have the popover displayed next to the autocomplete's menu item?

Comment: can you provide HTML as well

Comment: I added the html for the popover contents. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Check the answer and see if that is what you expect

Comment: Your fiddle works (mostly) as I'd expect. It's not displaying the div contents, but the popup is displayed in the correct location, and moves as I'd expect. Unfortunately, I'm not able to duplicate it in my project yet. I'm wondering if there's a Jquery or Bootstrap version mismatch.

Comment: check the jquery/bootstrap versions and let me know

Comment: For html inside the popover, the class "hide" should be removed. I have updated the fiddle. Check it

Comment: If the answer is good then set as right answer and up-vote. It will be useful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the open method of jQuery autocomplete as follows

```
open: function(event, ui) {
  var term = $(this).val();
  $(this).autocomplete("widget").find(".ui-menu-item")
    .popover({
      container: 'body',
      content: function() {
        return $('#SomeDiv').removeClass("hide");
      },
      html: true,
      trigger: 'hover'
    });
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/tn2433tu/2/

Comment: This is very close to solving the issue. I had to add the "'container':'body'" option to the popover. Make that change and I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One other note for future users, you need to return $('SomeDiv').html().removeClass('hide'); If you don't, the content div will get destroyed.